# Functions with interesting limit at infinity

Tags: calculus, integration

I came up with a formula to evaluate an integral. The formula is as follow:
$$\int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty \frac{f(t^x)f^{\ '}(t)}{1+x^2}\ dt\ dx=\ \frac{\pi}{4}(f^2(\infty)-f^2(0))$$
So now what I need are some functions $f$ to plug in. The requirement for $f$ is to have a limit at infinity. Obviously I plugged in
$$f(x)=e^{-x} \hspace{2cm} f(x)=\arctan(x)$$ and got two beautiful results, but I wonder if there are some other more interesting functions with a special value at infinity. Do you know any?

Comment: An immediate candidate for "neat values at infinity" is

$$f(x) = \left( 1 + \frac 1 x \right)^x \to e$$

or the more general

$$f(x) = \left( 1 + \frac \alpha x \right)^{\beta x} \to e^{\alpha \beta}$$

I'm really sure this question is concretely-framed enough to be useful, though. The question amounts to "what are some sufficiently-nice functions that have neat limits at infinity". Your standard special limits from calculus may apply; or the definition of certain constants like the Euler-Mascheroni constant; or the prime number theorem; the Stirling approximation; etc.

Comment: The left side and right sides of your formula  don’t match. What does it mean that you came up with a formula? What are you trying to evaluate? There are lots and lots of functions which have limits at infinity.

Comment: @Eric Yep, they do match.  Just try it on with $e^{-x}$ and $\arctan(x)$ if you don't believe me.

Comment: @PrincessEev Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Hmm, I stand corrected. Don’t know how it works but all my examples seem to work out…